# Attach the grease pencil to the camera

Tags: camera, grease-pencil

I want to be able to look through the camera and draw in the camera view. and have the grease pencil stay attached and oriented with the camera even if I adjust the position of the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Setting *Stroke Placement* to *View* should do the job.
[image]

In Blender 2.8, you can find the option here:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in 2.9 - I position the camera
- set placement to view
- add grease pencil -> strokes appears anywhere else but not on the view