# Align Grease Pencil with Camera Angle

Tags: camera, grease-pencil

I placed the camera on a certain position and want to start drawing with the grease pencil, but the lines appears somewhere else. Sure I can move them in front of the camera but I want it to be aligned correctly.

Someone asked here a similar question but it doesn't work for Blender 2.9. anymore.
[Attach the grease pencil to the camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130608/attach-the-grease-pencil-to-the-camera/206834?noredirect=1#comment348725_206834)

**Edit**

What I've tried:

- I position a new camera and and set it as active camera

[image: new cam]

- set it as active camera and added a blank grease pencil object.

[image: added blank]

- started drawing. looking good for the first impression but

[image: grease pencil draw]

- its seems that it's aligned to the first camera

[image: wrong alignement]

Answer (score 2):

The grease pencil strokes are aligned to the window in which you draw. Strokes will appear in a plane that is perpendicluar to the Z axis of the camera (or to whatever other view you want to draw in).

Here is an example that shows how to draw in camera view (press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>).

[image]

The distance to the camera, in which the grease pencil layer appears, is determined by the placement of the 3D cursor.

[image]

---

Note that the link posted on the question refers to the annotation tool, which is a different tool than the Grease Pencil

[image]

Comment: well this happens so smoothly because adding a grease pencil automaticly snaps to your camera view. It doesn't happen in my case. Camera is placed and set to active camera. Grease pencil appears in a strange position I cant relate on.

Comment: Please show what you get, it is hard to guess what you get, edit your question and show images that illustrate the problem.