# Can you draw in 3d from orthografic projections?

Tags: grease-pencil, orthographic

Im drawing a orthographic reference for my character, and then I would like to trace it in blender with grease pencil so I have a 3d-ish reference instead of several images.

Now, grease pencil only draws on a plane or the surface of an object as far as I know, so that's the question, is it possible to draw a stroke in front orthographic, and then again in left orthographic (for example), and have blender turn it into a single stroke in 3d space that looks like both?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is switch the view in which you want to draw, so that the strokes are aligned in a different axis.

[image]

Blender will not magically merge shapes, though.

But you can edit your objects just like any other object in 3D to get whatever shape and plane you want.

[image]

Note that you can also set the grease pencil to draw at different planes, determined by the 3d cursor. That would allow you to draw from the same view, but at different depths.

See: [Align Grease Pencil with Camera Angle](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/206886/align-grease-pencil-with-camera-angle/206919#206919)

Comment: This is good to know, although it was exactly that "magically merge" part I was wondering if was possible, since it's possible to convert a curve in 3d space to two orthographic 2d images and viceversa, I was asking to see if it was possible in blender.